# Executing .jar file from PHP through Command prompt

Tags: php, command-line, jar

I have a .jar file which has a command line interface. I want to call the jar file through command prompt and capture the output of the Jar file.

I have tried with the `exec()` command.

The command I have used is:

```
<?php
exec('java -jar D:\\Development\\Filehandler\\dist\\Filehandler.jar \ getConfigLang', $result);
echo $result;
echo $count = count($result);
for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++){
    print($result[$i]);
}

?>
```

The output for this was just '0 0'

Should something else be done before executing this command? like adding path etc???
I am using WAMP server.
Please help me...

Comment: You say, you have used that command, but what happened? An error, nothing, ...?

Comment: The length of the $result was '0'. No error at all.

Comment: Hi evil3, that's not working. Same behavior

Comment: Should something else be done to execute it?

Comment: And what will you get with these commands: 

exec('java -jar D:\\Development\\Filehandler\\dist\\Filehandler.jar \ getConfigLang', $result, $returnCode); var_dump($result); var_dump($returnCode);

Comment: Output for var_dump is:
array(0) { } int(0)

Comment: Well, it just seems that the .jar file does not have an output. I would try some simple .jar file that simply outputs a "hello world" message in order to know if the exec works correctly.

Comment: Hi Marty, I have tried with a simple jar file, and it works. Yet the intended file is not working. The Jar file needs some other libraries to run. I think, the problem lies with the additional libraries. Where should the additional libraries be placed?

Comment: It seems so. Look at my answer below. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try two approaches:

1) change current directory in PHP via function http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

```
<?php
chdir('D:\Development\Filehandler\dist');
exec('java -jar ./Filehandler.jar \ getConfigLang', $result);
...
?>
```

2) change .jar file: I don't know if it is possible but try to add these additional libraries with absolute paths.

Comment: Please, could you post here what solved your problem? Whether it was 1) or 2)?