# Executing Java Class from php web page in Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: java, php, windows, apache

I have a windows virtual machine in which I installed Bitnami Apache Web Server. I also have java class compiled as "myprogram.jar". I ran the jar file in the virtual machine's command prompt:

java -jar "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\wampstackXXX\apache2\htdocs\test\myprogram.jar"

and it is working fine. But now I have to run the java command from a php file ("run.php"). Here is the code snippet:

```
<?php 
   $cmd = "java -jar ".getcwd()."\myprogram.jar"
   echo $cmd;
   $output = shell_exec($cmd);
   echo $output;
?>
```

I use getcwd() to get the working directory of the php site in which I put the jar file in. I put this "run.php" file in the "C:\Program Files\Bitnami\wampstackXXX\apache2\htdocs\test" folder. But when I access the php file from my web browser, the java command is not firing. Is there something wrong that I did here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here [in on of the threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254268/executing-jar-file-from-php-through-command-prompt)

```
<?php
    chdir('C:\Program Files\Bitnami\wampstackXXX\apache2\htdocs\test');
    exec('java -jar myprogram.jar');
?>
```